# How can I redirect image 404 error on Amazon S3 to my own server

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-s3

Is it possible to redirect a 404 error on Amazon S3 server to my own server? Here's the case in my website:

A user uploaded a file, called abc.jpg. I have a set of image types, such as crop or thumb.

When someone access /img/abc.crop.jpg, the webserver check and look for the file /img/abc.crop.jpg. If they found it, webserver will throw the file.

But when the program can't found that file, this .htaccess file will route it to a program:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

So it will go to index.php/img/abc.crop.jpg, where the "img" controller/program will look for abc.jpg and generate a file called abc.crop.jpg on the img folder. So next time another user access the abc.crop.jpg, the program doesn't need to regenerate the file anymore.

Now, when I am using the Amazon S3, I have to generate ALL the different sizes (crop, thumb, etc) one by one to avoid 404 error. The purpose of the above technique is to conserve space. I wanted the flow to be kept consistent with the current condition. Anybody have any idea on how to manipulate S3 404 error so that they'll redirect to my server? Ie. http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/img/abc.crop.jpg redirect to http://mysite.com/img/abc.crop.jpg ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround to identifying the 404 error.

1. Enable S3 web service

   Configure the Error Document to a `file-not-found.jpg`

   `$result = $s3->getObject(array(
           'Bucket' => 'my bucket',
           'Key'    => 'path/to/file'
       ));`

   Use md5 or crc32 to identify if the returned object is `file-not-found.jpg`

   Redirect to your own server

Answer (score -1):

If you're using codeigniter, have a look at the reserved routes http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html. you can specify a specific controller for any 404 error.

Comment: I have used routing intensively, but I was talking about redirecting 404 in Amazon S3 to my own server, for the server to generate the file and upload it to S3. Next time a user look for that certain file, it will be there.